# How to make stream available over http?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an xml parser for a system I know virtually nothing about. I'm looking to set-up a local copy for the xml stream until I can have a look at the system providing the stream, so that I can write tests etc. in the meantime.

I was briefly shown that the xml stream is approached via http. It's an endless stream of data, if approached directly in the webbrowser it will eventually crash because the OS will run out of memory.

Now, I'm trying to set up the local stream server with fake data but I can't figure out how to make such a stream approachable via http. And is it correct to begin with?

```
public static Stream Create()
{
    var xmlDemo1 = TestResources.Strings.XmlResponseDataDemo(TestResources.Strings.XmlResponseDataDemoResource1);
    var demoDataLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(xmlDemo1.Length);
    var demoDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDemo1);

    Func<byte[]> getBytes = () =>
        {
            var ret1 = new byte[demoDataLengthBytes.Length + demoDataBytes.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(demoDataLengthBytes, 0, ret1, 0, demoDataLengthBytes.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(demoDataBytes, 0, ret1, demoDataLengthBytes.Length, demoDataBytes.Length);
            return ret1;
        };

    var ret = new MemoryStream();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var buffer = getBytes();
                ret.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        });

    return ret;
}
```

I'm prepending length to the bytes sent, which may not be necessary at all, but I can't figure that one out until later.